# HTMLAgilityPack - selecting nodes from node collection - instead of documentNode

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

My code looks like this:

```
var matchTableHtml =
            loginPage.DocumentNode
            .SelectNodes("//table[@id='uc_refereeMatchProgram_dgMatchCategory1']
                          //tr[@class!='DataGridHeaderStyle']");
```

This returns a collection of nodes - as intended, so no problem in that - but!!!

```
var testing = matchTableHtml.Descendants()
            .Select(x => new Match()
                             {
                                 Row = x.SelectSingleNode("//td/a[position()=1]")
                                       .InnerText
                             });
```

Here 'x' returns the node from the documentNode and not from the 'matchTableHtml.Descendants'-collection. Anybody who knows why?

Answer (score 2):

Ok - the solution was very simple... I was not starting from 'current node' but the XPath starting with // is of course relative to the root node.

Simple solution - add a dot - which gives denotes that we start from current ('//' ==> './/'):

```
Row = x.SelectSingleNode(".//td/a[position()=1]")
                                   .InnerText
```